# PHPMailer: Recipient address rejected: You cannot send email using FROM address different than your login

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, mantis

I have a problem with emails into mantis. How can I fix this problem?

Log:

```
2016-06-19 10:38 CEST mail message #165 queued
2016-06-19 10:38 CEST mail Password reset for user @U11 sent to mail@mail.com
2016-06-19 10:38 CEST mail Processing e-mail queue (1 messages)
2016-06-19 10:38 CEST mail Sending message #165 queued on 2016-06-19 10:38 CEST
2016-06-19 10:38 CEST mail ERROR: Message could not be sent - SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: mail@mail.com<p>SMTP server error: 5.7.1 <mail@mail.com>: Recipient address rejected: You cannot send email using FROM address different than your login. 773d.576659f9.52d4c.0
```

Config:

```
$g_allow_signup = ON;
$g_enable_email_notification = ON;
$g_phpMailer_method = PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP;
$g_smtp_host = 'xx.pl';
$g_smtp_username = 'xx@xx.pl';
$g_smtp_password = 'yy';
$g_smtp_connection_mode = 'tls';
$g_smtp_port = 587;
$g_from_email = 'xx@xx.pl';
$g_from_name = 'Xx';
$g_max_lost_password_in_progress_count = 100;
$g_email_send_using_cronjob = OFF;
$g_log_level = LOG_EMAIL | LOG_EMAIL_RECIPIENT | LOG_FILTERING | LOG_AJAX;
$g_log_destination = 'file:/mantis.log';
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just added $g_return_path_email to config file and it works now

Answer (score 1):

Like it says - it doesn't allow sending using a from address different to your login. This is down to your ISP, but be aware that it's not unusual - gmail does the same, though it does allow you to predefine aliases as alternative from addresses.

Comment: Set SMTPDebug=2 and post what it says in your question.